# Table td width issue - Can't restrict it

Tags: html, css, html-table

Code:

```css
.table1,
.table2 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.table1 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.table1 tr td,
.table2 tr td {
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 200%;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.table2 tr:first-child {
  border-bottom: 4px double #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <table class="table2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="checkall" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
          Autor
        </td>
        <td>
          Komentarz
        </td>
        <td>
          Data dodania
        </td>
        <td>
          Post
        </td>
        <td>
          Status
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          cipka|cipuszka@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadasdsad </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-03 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="4">
        </td>
        <td>
          cipka|cipuszka@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sako </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-04 </td>
        <td>
          Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc! </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="5">
        </td>
        <td>
          Cipenia|Cifuszka@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          aoskdopaskdop



        </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-04 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="6">
        </td>
        <td>
          Cifaretka|cifunia@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          oakspodkpoasdasd </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-04 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="11">
        </td>
        <td>
          sadsadsadsad|sadsadas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadsadas </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-09 </td>
        <td>
          Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc! </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="12">
        </td>
        <td>
          asdksd|asdasdas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sfkdskpofksdfdsfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="13">
        </td>
        <td>
          asdksd|asdasdas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sfkdskpofksdfdsfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="14">
        </td>
        <td>
          asdksdCIA|asdasdas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sfkdskpofksdfdsfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="15">
        </td>
        <td>
          Fajny|komentarz@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          opkpodkadadsad </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="16">
        </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsf|dsdsf@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-16 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="17">
        </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsf|dsdfgdsf@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-16 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="90">
        </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsfdsf|dsfds@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-17 </td>
        <td>
          Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc! </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that this table have issue with width on `td`.
Look, it is like:

[image]

And it should look like:

[image]

I got 6 `td`'s. So I even set width to `100/6` = `15` or `16%`.

Tried with `max-width: 16%`. Still nothing. These `td`'s… can't control their width. Totally don't know how to fix this.

Comment: First of all, use th for the table headings and it'll line them all up, if you want to change the width of each td then give them a class or an id and style them indivually with css

Comment: I want all of them to have one, specific width, 16% for all. For 6 tds. So width is equal for all of them

Answer (score 2):

```css
.table1, .table2 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.table1 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.table1 tr td, .table2 tr td {
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 200%;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.table2 tr:first-child {
  border-bottom: 4px double #444;
}

table tr th{
  border-bottom: 4px double #444;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <table class="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <input id="checkall" type="checkbox">
        </th>
        <th>
          Autor
        </th>
        <th>
          Komentarz
        </th>
        <th>
          Data dodania
        </th>
        <th>
          Post
        </th>
        <th>
          Status
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          cipka|cipuszka@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadasdsad </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-03 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="4">
        </td>
        <td>
          cipka|cipuszka@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sako </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-04 </td>
        <td>
          Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc! </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="5">
        </td>
        <td>
          Cipenia|Cifuszka@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          aoskdopaskdop



        </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-04 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="6">
        </td>
        <td>
          Cifaretka|cifunia@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          oakspodkpoasdasd </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-04 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="11">
        </td>
        <td>
          sadsadsadsad|sadsadas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadsadas </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-09 </td>
        <td>
          Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc! </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="12">
        </td>
        <td>
          asdksd|asdasdas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sfkdskpofksdfdsfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="13">
        </td>
        <td>
          asdksd|asdasdas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sfkdskpofksdfdsfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="14">
        </td>
        <td>
          asdksdCIA|asdasdas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sfkdskpofksdfdsfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="15">
        </td>
        <td>
          Fajny|komentarz@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          opkpodkadadsad </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="16">
        </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsf|dsdsf@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-16 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="17">
        </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsf|dsdfgdsf@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-16 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="90">
        </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsfdsf|dsfds@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-17 </td>
        <td>
          Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc! </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your table rows to have equal width, you can set equal `table-layout: fixed` for your table. In this case you don't need to set `td`'s width explicitly.

```css
.table1,
.table2 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.table1 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.table1 tr td,
.table2 tr td {
  line-height: 200%;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.table2 tr:first-child {
  border-bottom: 4px double #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <table class="table2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="checkall" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
          Autor
        </td>
        <td>
          Komentarz
        </td>
        <td>
          Data dodania
        </td>
        <td>
          Post
        </td>
        <td>
          Status
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          cipka|cipuszka@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadasdsad </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-03 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="4">
        </td>
        <td>
          cipka|cipuszka@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sako </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-04 </td>
        <td>
          Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc! </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="5">
        </td>
        <td>
          Cipenia|Cifuszka@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          aoskdopaskdop



        </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-04 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="6">
        </td>
        <td>
          Cifaretka|cifunia@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          oakspodkpoasdasd </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-04 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="11">
        </td>
        <td>
          sadsadsadsad|sadsadas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadsadas </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-09 </td>
        <td>
          Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc! </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="12">
        </td>
        <td>
          asdksd|asdasdas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sfkdskpofksdfdsfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="13">
        </td>
        <td>
          asdksd|asdasdas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sfkdskpofksdfdsfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="14">
        </td>
        <td>
          asdksdCIA|asdasdas@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sfkdskpofksdfdsfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="15">
        </td>
        <td>
          Fajny|komentarz@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          opkpodkadadsad </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-13 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="16">
        </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsf|dsdsf@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-16 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="17">
        </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsf|dsdfgdsf@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          sadfsdfsdf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-16 </td>
        <td>
          Przykładowy Tytuł Strony </td>
        <td>
          0 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="90">
        </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsfdsf|dsfds@o2.pl </td>
        <td>
          dsfdsfdsf </td>
        <td>
          2017-06-17 </td>
        <td>
          Burde lubie kielbaske se zjesc! </td>
        <td>
          1 </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```